# Where's the catch? Game involving taking turns choosing $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$ that all commute with each other.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

> Let $S$ be the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p.$ Alice and Bob take turns choosing elements of $S$ such that no element is repeated and every element must commute with all previous matrices. Whoever cannot move loses. Who wins?

My solution: Let $A = \{ X \in S : X^2 = I\}, B = \{ X \in S : X^2 = -I\}, C = S \setminus (A \cup B).$ If $p \ne 2,$ then $X \ne -X$ for all $X \in S.$ Thus, Bob may win by playing $f(X)$ if Alice plays $X,$ where $$f(X) = \begin{cases} -X, \, X \in A \text{ or } X \in B \text{ and n odd}\\ X^{-1}, \text{ else} \end{cases}.$$ Suppose Alice just played $X$ and previously played $Y \ne X.$ To show Bob never repeats a move, it suffices to show that $f(X) \notin \{Y, f(Y)\}.$ Since $f$ is an involution, $f(X) \in \{Y,f(Y)\} \Rightarrow X \in \{f(Y), Y\},$ which means Alice repeated a move and already lost. Thus, Bob wins if $p \ne 2.$

Suppose $p = 2$ and $X \in A.$ The minimal polynomial of $X$ divides $t^2 - 1 = (t-1)^2 \mod 2,$ so the only eigenvalue of $X$ is $1.$ Let $X = PJP^{-1}$ and let $J_i = I + N$ where $N$ is the matrix with ones on the diagonal right above the main one be a Jordan block of $J.$ We must have $I = J_i^2 = I + N^2 \Rightarrow N^2 = 0 \Rightarrow J_i$ has size $1$ or $2.$

I suspect that in the case $p = 2,$ Alice wins by playing $I,$ then playing $X^{-1}$ whenever Bob plays $X \notin A,$ but I have no idea what she should do in the case $X \in A$ is played. For $n=1,2,$ we can see that Alice wins easily, but trying to analyze all $n$ choices for $J$ is unfeasible for larger $n$ since we have tons of choices for $P$ as well. I believe the catch is that this final case is much harder than the rest of the problem, and I've only scratched the surface of the tip of the iceberg when it comes to solving it. How should I proceed? Any hints, approaches, or ideas?

If we look for a strategy involving just polynomials, we will observe that $\mathbb{F}_2[X]/\langle X^2 - 1 \rangle = \{ O, I, X, X+I\}.$ However, $(X+I)^2 = X^2 + I = 2I = O$ and the other choices are not viable either. Thus, our strategy (which ostensibly must rely on performing some sensible operations on the set of previously played matrices) has to rely on the products of matrices. But which matrices shall we multiply?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I'm not sure what you mean (certainly not George Singer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Singer_(cycle_manufacturer)), the 1st result when I searched "Singer cycle"), but this number is odd if $p = 2.$

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Why is this true? I suspected it might be the case, but if $a^2=b^2=e$ for $a, b \in G$ and $G$ is a group, that does not tell us $ab=ba.$ We need $(ab)^2 = e.$

Comment: Mea culpa — that's just wrong. on my part. (In particular, the 3d permutation matrices that swap $(x, y)$ an $(y, z)$ are both order two but don't commute.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Only the invertible matrices. Question updated.

Comment: Just a random idea for $p \neq 2$, I‘m not too sure it works. Bob gives a yet-unused scalar multiple of the matrix Alice just gave. It’s always possible because a matrix of $S$ has $p-1$ scalar multiples in $S$ including itself (thus, an even number), so it’s Alice who loses in the end.

Comment: This is problem B5 from the 2014 Putnam exam:  https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2014.pdf.

Comment: When $p=2$, there is a matrix $M$ with irreducible minimal polynomial $\mu$ of degree $n$ and with simple roots in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$. Then an $\mathbb{F}_2$-matrix commutes with $M$ iff it’s in the $n$-dimensional algebra $A$ of polynomials in $M$. Now, $A \cap S=A^{\times}=A \backslash \{0\}$ (as $A \equiv \mathbb{F}_2[X]/(\mu)$) has odd cardinality, and is commutative. So if Alice starts by saying $M$, Bob and Alice take turns exhausting the elements of $A^{\times}$ and Alice wins.

Comment: @Mindlack I get every part of your argument except the "only if". How do we know that every matrix which is not a polynomial in $M$ does not commute with $M$? This seems tantamount to the result on Singer cycles I could not find a reference for.

Comment: The proof is in two steps. Step 1: the rank of the commutant of a matrix doesn’t depend on the base field (it’s the dimension of the space of solution of a certain system). Step 2: if a $n \times n$ matrix with coefficients in a field $F$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues in $F$, its commutant has dimension $n$ (just diagonalize, so you can consider a matrix with pairwise disjoint entries).

Comment: @Mindlack What is the commutant of "a matrix"? The vector space of matrices that commute with it? This has a dimension, but not a rank.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I call the commutant of a matrix. I thought one could say that a vector space had a rank (as a synonym for dimension), but if you say the opposite...